# Why isn't my view updating using js.erb file? (Rails 4)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following [this tutorial](http://buckybits.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/simple-ajax-property-toggle-in-rails-30.html) to toggle an attribute in my database. The toggle functionality works but I can't seem to update my view to reflect the changes. I've never used js.erb files before so there may be something completely obvious that I've missed.

My controller action:

```
def toggle_menu
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page.toggle!(:menu)
    render nothing: true
end
```

My view:

```
<td><%= link_to "Navigation", toggle_menu_page_path(page),remote: true, id: "menu_button_#{page.id}", class: menu_button(page) %></td>
```

My toggle_menu.js.erb file:

```
$("menu_button_<%= page.id %>").text("foo");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following line, because it prevents Rails to look for the toggle_menu.js.erb view:

```
render nothing: true
```

And replace `page` by `@page` in the toggle_menu.js.erb.